# c for ti84 Constant integer expression expected

Tags: c

I'm writing c code for ti84 plus CE calculator because I'd like to use my functions I wrote for my PC on my calculator. I use an online IDE to compile my programs into the .8xp format that my calculator needs.

When I build this function:

```
void main(void){
     int x =5;
     double array[x];
}
```

I get this error: "Constant integer expression expected"

Comment: So your compiler does not support VLAs (variable-length arrays). BTW, this function does nothing

Comment: `void main(void)` is an invalid signature for `main`

Comment: Use a standard compliant compiler which support VLAs. Or a C99 compiler.

Comment: [TIGCC](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/) is supposed to support VLAs according to "[Arrays of Variable Length](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC76)"